# Startup Convertible note write-off debt?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, debt-collection, debt-discharge

I invested time in a tech start-up during 2013 that has since closed its doors.

I received payment in the form of convertible notes... $30,000 in total, which of course have no value now.

Is there any sort of tax write-off I'm able to take from this?

Comment: It would help to know what country you're at. Tax law differs from place to place.

Comment: I'm in the US.. good question :)

Answer (score 2):

In the US, you can deduct this as a "bad debt".

Since it's an investment, it is a *personal* bad debt, and as such it has to be *totally* unrecoverable. Personal bad debts are deducted as short term capital losses using [form 8949](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-8949,-Sales-and-Other-Dispositions-of-Capital-Assets).

See more information, and links to the relevant forms and instructions, [here on the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc453.html) site.

---

I missed a crucial word in your question... You invested **time**, and received notes in return for the **time** invested, not **cash**.

You can only deduct bad debt if you invested **cash**, or paid taxes on the notes when you received them. If you didn't pay taxes on the notes when you received them, then the debt is **not** deductible.